# Delphi JCL and passes the Marshall object through the interface, it raise an exception in Delphi, it is rethrown correctly in C# - HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF

Tags: c#, delphi, interface, marshalling

I want to catch exception thrown in Delphi witch pass to C# library as interface using JCL.
The exception is caught but there is 0x8000FFFF.
What do I do wrong?

Delphi code:

```
unit TestClass;

interface

uses
  SysUtils,
  JcLDotNet;

type
  ITestService = interface['{7B07D16A-72AE-4DD3-8959-B1EC6C6241B7}']
    procedure Call(); safecall;
  end;

  TTestService = class(TInterfacedObject, ITestService)
    procedure Call(); safecall;
  end;

  TSimpleClass = class
    FHost : TJclClrHost;
    FCSharp: OleVariant;
    constructor Create();
    procedure Call();
  end;

implementation


procedure TSimpleClass.Call;
begin
  FCSharp.Call;
end;

constructor TSimpleClass.Create();
var
  testService : TTestService;
begin
  FHost := TJclClrHost.Create('v4.0.30319');
  FHost.Start;
  FCSharp := FHost.DefaultAppDomain.CreateInstance('CSharpLibrary','CSharpLibrary.TestClass').Unwrap;
  //
  testService := TTestService.Create();
  FCSharp.SetService(ITestService(IUnknown(testService)));
end;

procedure TTestService.Call();
begin
  raise Exception.Create('throw exception');
end;

end.
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CSharpLibrary
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("7B07D16A-72AE-4DD3-8959-B1EC6C6241B7"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface ITestService
    {
        void Call();
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        private ITestService _testService;

        public void SetService(ITestService testService)
        {
            _testService = testService;
        }

        void Call()
        {
            try
            {
                _testService.Call();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                // error: 0x8000FFFF E_UNEXPECTED
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);  
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to execute the example and it doesn't pass the exception corectly.
Debuging C# library catch exception but 0x8000FFFF.

Comment: Burn the [witch](https://www.oed.com/discover/witch/?tl=true). :D

Comment: Give your class TTestService  a destructor and see when it is called!

Comment: The destructor in Delphi doesn't work because I didn't run Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_testService); on the C# side. When I debug, procedure Call from Delphi service is executed - the problem still occurs on raising exception. How to pass an exception message as a result of this procedure ?